# Python3.5 and os.makedirs() not working

Tags: python, path, directory, operating-system

In my python script is a method that should create parent directory for path defined in input. Script finishes without any exception, but no directory was created. I run python3.5 in Ubuntu 14.04.

```
def create_parent_directory(path):
    dir_name = os.path.dirname(path)
    if not os.path.exists(dir_name) and not dir_name == "":
        os.makedirs(dir_name)
```

I made a second script just with this method and the problem is still the same, so it really is this method that is faulty. It looks like os.path.exists(dir_name) is not working either.

Is my input the problem? The command I use when I want the directory to be created in same place as where the script lies is srip.py MyPath.
Should I use something like scrip.py /home/bla/blabla/MyPath ? Or should I use relative path in my script?

Comment: What is the value in your `path` in `create_parent_directory(path)`?

Answer (score 0):

The directory you're trying to create already exists.

`os.path.dirname("/home/bla/blabla/MyPath")` returns the directory that `MyPath` is in, that is, `/home/bla/blabla`. If your script lies in the directory `/home/bla/blabla`, and you want to create a `MyPath` directory in the same directory,

```
def create_parent_directory(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path) and not path == "":
        os.makedirs(path)
```